# FQL: Retrieving Photo Upload Posts on Group Stream Table

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Let's say I have a simple query like the one below, where source_id is a group.

```
SELECT post_id,message,attachment FROM stream WHERE source_id=xxxxx
```

My question is pretty straightforward. How do I get posts that are the result of a user uploading a photo to an album? With the above query, they don't show up, even though clearly a post is created on the group's wall.

Interestingly enough, if you use source_id = me(), then the query works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

what coding language are you using? I just tested this in the Graph Explorer, it returned  results.

Where i used a group id of which i could see. and i think the attachment->media key had something called fb_object_type = 'album' on some of the results.

Also make sure you set the right permissions.

Maybe you can use that?

Comment: Yeah, even with a full permission set in the Graph API Explorer, and I'm not seeing the posts. I should note that this seems to work for photos that are just posted to the wall, but **not** for photos that are uploaded directly to a group album.

Comment: I have the sinking feeling that this may be deliberate on Facebook's part, since the Graph API cannot access photos in group photo albums (even public ones). It would therefore make sense that any corresponding group feed posts wouldn't be visible either.

Comment: Sometimes you will experience different results if you in the Graph Api Explorer set it to use your own app instead of the Graph Api Explorer. But yeah you will only get the wall feed, else you might wanna try something like getting the feed getting the id of the those fb_type_object 'album', saving it to and array implode(",") on the array and querying the album or photo table by the album id, but basically you will have to have 2 requests then. Dunno if it would work just a thought. Meaning SELECT aid FROM album WHERE aid IN (theImplodedArray)

Comment: Because when a user uploads a photo to the album it should show up on the group wall right? :-) That the user have uploaded an photo. Then logically it would be in the feed, but i know facebook is weird.

Comment: True, that's exactly what I'm getting at. I actually suspect that this might be a bug within the Graph API, based on the fact that apparently we're supposed to be able to query group photo albums. I reported this issue at https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/216761925185393/.